# want to understand a C array behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, memory-address

Please see the following code snippet:

```
int main()
{

    int arr[] = { 0,3 , 4,28,1198};
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("\n arr[i] %u \n" , arr+i);
    printf("\n *******************\n");
    printf("%u ", &arr+1);

    return 1;

}
```

When it is run, it outputs:

```
arr[i] 3219650892 

 arr[i] 3219650896 

 arr[i] 3219650900 

 arr[i] 3219650904 

 arr[i] 3219650908 

 *******************
3219650912
```

It seems that it is showing me the last element's address added with 1 more integer which seems to be strange. I feel it should have given me address of second element.

Can you help me understand this behavior?

Comment: &arr means (char*)[5], +1 means +5 index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To understand this, compare the meaning of `arr` with `&arr`.

`arr` is the name for the array. C has a rule that an array expression is converted to a pointer to the first element (except in some particular situations that do not apply here). So `arr` is converted to `&arr[0]`, which is the address of the first element. This is a pointer to `int`, so, when you add 1 to it, you get a pointer to the next `int`. Thus, successive increments to this pointer increment through elements of the array.

In contrast, `&arr` is a pointer to the array.<sup>*</sup> The starting address of the array and the starting address of the first element are the same, but they have different types. The type of `&arr` is ”pointer to array of five int”. When you add 1 to this, you get a pointer to the next array of five int. That is, the address is incremented by the size of an entire array of five int.

Incidentally, it is inappropriate to use a `%u` specifier to print addresses. You should use `%p` and convert the addresses to `void *`, such as:

```
printf("%p ", (void *) (&arr+1));
```

**Footnote**

<sup>*</sup> This is one of those special situations: When an array is used with `&`, the conversion is not done. In `&arr`, `arr` is the array, not a pointer, and `&arr` is its address.

Answer (score 3):

`&arr+1`

`&arr` is a pointer to the array `arr`, so `&arr + 1` points at the address of the last element of `arr` array `+ 1` element. That is `arr` last element address is `&arr[4]` so `&arr + 1` is the same address as `&arr[5]` (but the type is different).

Answer (score 0):

&arr gives you the pointer to array of 5 integers.

hence, &arr+1 points to next array of  5 integers.